# Unable to get Pointer to an Array working - Application Crashes

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to work with pointer to an array. I am unable to get the below code working. Looks very small issue, but could not find it.

Secondly, some people say `int[4] *ptrToArray;` is equivalent to `int (* ptrToArray)[4];` Is this correct? But it is not compiling in my case.

```
#define NUM_COLS 4
#define NUM_ROWS 3

int main()
{
    unsigned char colNum;
    int simple_array[NUM_COLS];
    int (* ptrToArray)[NUM_COLS];   //int[4] *ptrToArray???
    ptrToArray = &simple_array;

    for(colNum=0;colNum<NUM_COLS;colNum++)
    {
        *(ptrToArray)[colNum] =colNum;
    }
    for(colNum=0;colNum<NUM_COLS;colNum++)
    {
       printf("%d\t",*(ptrToArray)[colNum]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Edit:
 I am trying to understand the concept of pointer to an array in the text book Let Us C by Yeshwant Kanetkar. Below is the code snippet from the text book. I tried for only one row though.
[image]

Comment: `int[4] ptrToArray;` is not valid grammar. But `int p[4]` is identical to `int (p)[4]`. The parenthesis are useless here. You got some parenthesis wrong, correct parentesis are crucial. See the info page for hints how to read complex declarators.

Comment: You are using things that are not defined and... other stuff that makes little sense.  What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: Sorry, I am not an expert. I am trying to fill the array and then print it back to understand the concept of pointer to Array (int (*p)[]). It is bit confusing to me. I just started with only one row and later it will be extended to n rows and m columns.

Comment: I entered int[4] *ptrToArray. But * is missing. If I edit I can see the *. Why so? Or even small portion like this also has to be entered as a code block?

Comment: You say that "it is not compiling in my case"; please clarify this by adding the compilation errors to your question. If the errors mention a line number, please mention which line they refer to.

Comment: Not compiling only if I use other declaration int[4] *ptrToArray; instead of int (*ptrToArray)[4]; This was my second part of the question. Otherwise whatever code I put above compiles. But application crashes if I run.

Comment: This is very important info; please add it to the question. Currently the question states "unable to get the below code working", which is absolutely useless in describing your problem. Please state in your question that your code crashes, and specify where (in which line in code; also, does it output anything before it crashes?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is more usual to use pointers to the first element of the array, like this:

```
    int *ptrToArray;

    ptrToArray = simple_array; // decays to &simple_array[0]
```

Then you can access the elements of the original array through the pointer like so:

```
    ptrToArray[colNum] = colNum;
```

---

It is possible to point to the array itself as you have done:

```
    int (*ptrToArray)[NUM_COLS];

    ptrToArray = &simple_array;
```

However, your code to access the elements of the array is incorrect due to operator precedence and association errors.  The index operator `[]` has higher precedence than the dereference operator `*`, so your code should be like this:

```
    (*ptrToArray)[colNum] = colNum;
```

`(*ptrToArray)` dereferences the pointer to a value of type `int [NUM_COLS]`. That will decay to a pointer (`int *`) to the first element of the array, and the `[numCols]` will perform the array indexing operation on the pointer. Here, it should be noted that the expression `((a)[i])` is equivalent to `(*((a) + (i)))`.

Comment: Great. Works fine now. Many of those who commented did not understand my question at all. Many of them gave negative points without really understanding the question and not sure why? I think the question is valid and clear and small issue I had in de-referencing. Hope negative points are reversed.

Answer (score 0):

```
int arr[4]; //array of int

int *arr[4]; //array of int*. This is similar to int* arr[4];
```

In the first case, each element in the array is an `int`. Example: `arr[0]` holds the value `1`.

In the second case, each element in the array is a `pointer-to-int`. Example: `arr[0]` holds the value `FF0EBX0C`.

Back to the first case `int arr[4]`. The "pointer to an array" (which you are asking about) is actually just `arr` itself without `[]`. In fact, it is actually just the address of the first element of the array.

If you do:

```
printf("address of arr: %p\n", arr);
printf("address of first element of arr: %p\n", &(arr[0]));
```

You will see that they have the same value.

Comment: See my Edit in original post. I am not talking about Array of Pointers. Instead Pointer to an Array.

Answer (score 0):

For one and two dimentional array use these lines:
    int array [ARRAY_LEN];
    int array_2dims [RAW_ARRAY_LEN][COL_ARRAY_LEN];
If you use the * sign in your array definition, you should use dynamic allocation or the static variable address to set your pointer and using that.